# How can I upload a file multiple times?

Tags: java, excel, file, upload

This is my code, I am here accept excell file and read it .After than I read of excell file of row values and insert them to database,which to the appropriate columns. At the end, I put the file in the folder that I have determined on the computer. But I am having a problem here,When I want to download the file with the same name a few times in the api, it shows that I only uploaded first time it to the folder at first,but it prints the values to the database. I can't make any logic about it, what do you think I can do here?

```
 @Override
    public ResponseEntity<? extends Response> acceptExcelFileAndSenderName(MultipartFile filePath, String senderName) throws IOException {
        String fileName = filePath.getOriginalFilename();
        if (fileName.substring(fileName.length() - 5).equals(".xlsx")) {
            try (InputStream excelFile = filePath.getInputStream()) {
                String phoneNumber = "";
                String textMessage = "";
                Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
                Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                        Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
                        if (currentCell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                            phoneNumber = NumberToTextConverter.toText(currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
                        } else if (currentCell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
                            textMessage = String.valueOf(currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                        }

                    }
                    FileDetail fileDetail = new FileDetail();
                    fileDetail.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
                    fileDetail.setTextMessage(textMessage);
                    fileDetail.setSender(senderName);
                    this.fileDetailRepository.save(fileDetail);
                }
                excelFile.close();

                String destination = "C:\\Users\\anar.memmedov\\Desktop\\app\\" + filePath.getOriginalFilename();
                File file1 = new File(destination);
                filePath.transferTo(file1);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(new SuccessResponse(MessageCase.FILE_SUCCESSFULLY_WRITTEN_TO_DATABASE.getMessage(), 200), HttpStatus.OK);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponse(MessageCase.FAILED_HAPPEND_WHEN_FILE_WRITTEN_TO_DATABASE.getMessage(), 400), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try creating a unique file name for every file, eg:

```
String destination = "C:\\Users\\anar.memmedov\\Desktop\\app\\" + System.nanoTime()+"_"+filePath.getOriginalFilename();
```

Comment: Great Answer, much thanks!

Comment: It worked, but what I want is the current date instead of a random number - my file is named - _ for example When I upload file, I want to it looks like this
10.19.2021-4:19 PM-file_name_

Comment: then instead of `System.nanoTime()` put `new Date()`

Comment: I am getting error java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\anar.memmedov\Desktop\app\_Tue Oct 19 16:35:26 AZT 2021_test.xlsx (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: oooh yeah the problem is the special character `:`

Comment: What can I do, can you briefly write the code?

Comment: Windows doesnt allow a colon(:) in the file name. I suggest you revert back to `System.nanoTime()`. This is simply a numeric representation of the current date, its not a random number

Comment: I need this unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some things and worked, and it looks like this

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
    
                    String destination = "C:\\Users\\anar.memmedov\\Desktop\\app\\" + "_" + LocalDateTime.now().format(dateTimeFormatter) + "_" + filePath.getOriginalFilename();
```